# libxml accessing content of node cause application exit

Tags: c++, libxml2

I'm a beginner with libxml and I encounter a strange behaviour :
When I try to access to the content of and xmlNode, the application exits silently.

My code :

```
// Initialisation des pointeurs
xmlDocPtr doc;
xmlXPathContextPtr xpath_context;
xmlXPathObjectPtr xpath_objects;

// Chargement du document et création du contexte pour xpath
doc = xmlParseFile(nom.c_str());
xpath_context = xmlXPathNewContext(doc);

// Recherche via xpath
xpath_objects = xmlXPathEvalExpression((xmlChar*)("//personnage/nom"), xpath_context);
if(xpath_objects == NULL)
    cout << "La balise nom est obligatoire !\n";

// Affichage des résultats
cout << "Nom de la balise : " << xpath_objects->nodesetval->nodeTab[0]->name << "\n";
cout << "Valeur de la balise : " << (char*)(xpath_objects->nodesetval->nodeTab[0]->content) << "\n";
cout << "Fin\n";

// Libération de la mémoire
xmlXPathFreeObject(xpath_objects);
xmlXPathFreeContext(xpath_context);
xmlFreeDoc(doc);
```

My XML file :

```
<personnage>

    <nom>Toto</nom>

</personnage>
```

Description of xmlNode :

```
Structure xmlNode
struct _xmlNode {
    void *  _private    : application data
    xmlElementType  type    : type number, must be second !
    const xmlChar * name    : the name of the node, or the entity
    struct _xmlNode *   children    : parent->childs link
    struct _xmlNode *   last    : last child link
    struct _xmlNode *   parent  : child->parent link
    struct _xmlNode *   next    : next sibling link
    struct _xmlNode *   prev    : previous sibling link
    struct _xmlDoc *    doc : the containing document End of common p
    xmlNs * ns  : pointer to the associated namespace
    xmlChar *   content : the content
    struct _xmlAttr *   properties  : properties list
    xmlNs * nsDef   : namespace definitions on this node
    void *  psvi    : for type/PSVI informations
    unsigned short  line    : line number
    unsigned short  extra   : extra data for XPath/XSLT
}
```

Full documentation is available here : http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlNode

And this is the output :

```
Nom de la balise : nom
Valeur de la balise : damien@caturday:~$
```

Could someone help me please ?

Thanks,

Damien

Comment: @DumbCoder No, I haven't found the solution yet. If I remove `cout << "Valeur de la balise : " << (char*)(xpath_objects->nodesetval->nodeTab[0]->content) << "\n";` the application don't exit with error.

Comment: The XML DOM is somewhat unintuitive here.  You need to access nodeTab[0]->children->content as "Toto" is the content of an unnamed text node that is the child of the "nom" element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, as Luke says, for libxml, the content of an xmlNode is an another node.
So we have to access to the children to read the content of the selected node.

In my case, the solution is :

```
cout << "Valeur de la balise : " << (char*)(xpath_objects->nodesetval->nodeTab[0]->children->content) << "\n";
```

Thank you Luke.